# Populating table from database

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I am trying to populate a table with the query results I receive from a function. I am able to populate the table however my table header keeps repeating in each row. Is the any way I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put table header outside of your `while` loop:

```
echo '<table border="1" style="width:100%">';
           echo '<tr><td> Dep</td><td> Style</td> <td> Colour</td><td> Description</td> <td> Price</td></tr>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get5star)){

           echo'<tr><td> '.$row['departmentid']. '</td><td>'.$row['style']. '</td> <td> '.$row['colour']. '</td> <td> '.$row['description']. '</td> <td>'.$row['price'].'</td> </tr>';

           }
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

because your table's head part is inside of loop
you should do like this 
for example we get book names and writer's name :

```
    <table>
<thead>
<th>book></th>
<th>writer</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get5star)){


           echo'
<tr><td> '.$row['book']. '</td><td>'.$row['writer']. '</td> </tr>
';

           }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> however my table header keeps repeating in each row

That's because it's inside the loop.  The general structure of a loop is:

```
(stuff that happens once)
while (some condition) {
    (stuff that happens many times)
}
(stuff that happens once)
```

If the UI table header should happen only once (which it should), then it needs to go in one of those `(stuff that happens once)` locations.  In this case, the first one:

```
// happens once
echo '<table border="1" style="width:100%">';
echo '<tr><td> Dep</td><td> Style</td> <td> Colour</td><td> Description</td> <td> Price</td></tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get5star)){
    // happens many times
    echo'<tr><td> '.$row['departmentid']. '</td><td>'.$row['style']. '</td> <td> '.$row['colour']. '</td> <td> '.$row['description']. '</td> <td>'.$row['price'].'</td> </tr>';
}

// happens once
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the table head code inside the loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get5star)){
   echo '<tr><td> Dep</td><td> Style</td> <td> Colour</td><td> Description</td> <td> Price</td></tr>';
```

You should put that outside the while loop, like this:

```
echo '<table border="1" style="width:100%">';
echo '<tr><td> Dep</td><td> Style</td> <td> Colour</td><td> Description</td> <td> Price</td></tr>';
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get5star)){
       echo'<tr><td> '.$row['departmentid']. '</td><td>'.$row['style']. '</td> <td> '.$row['colour']. '</td> <td> '.$row['description']. '</td> <td>'.$row['price'].'</td> </tr>';
           }
echo '</table>';
```

Worth noticing that you shouldnt use mysql , to access the Database. Use [PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) ( i prefer them ) or mysqli .